# save and load Checkbox status across multiple devices

Tags: javascript, checkbox, storage, local, status

I am currently working on a project where I have to create a "website" that will only be launched on the intranet server of a company. 
So there is a user interface with 5 checkbox on it. Currently I am storing the checkbox status in the local storage like this:

```html
<script>
var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {},
    $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");

 console.log(checkboxValues);
  
$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
  $checkboxes.each(function(){
    checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
  });
  
  localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
});

// On page load
$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
  $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});
</script>
```

This works fine so far! 
However now the problem I am struggling with for almost a week now:

The checkbox status have to be the same on every device... e.g if I am ticking a checkbox from one device the checkbox needs to be ticked by the next f5 on all other devices... 
I hope you guys can help me out and have some alternatives to store the checkbox status.

Thank you very much !

All the best

poza

Comment: Store the status on server side and fetch it on load.

Answer (score 1):

As stated here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

> The localStorage and sessionStorage properties allow to save key/value
>   pairs in a web browser.

This means that your checkbox status is saved client-side. But, instead of refreshing the status on all client devices separately, I would recommend you to save the status on your server itself (json-file, database, etc.).

Your clients could send then a so-called [fetch-request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) in JavaScript, to get the status code.

I hope this helps.